# Sending a memory file to the client browser via asp.net works on Edge, IE, and Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some generic code that I use to send files from the server to the client. I'm sending a pdf file and everything works fine in debug on my local machine no matter which browser I use. However, when I deploy onto a server the file only downloads properly with the Edge, IE or Firefox browsers but not with Chrome.

With Chrome I get a "Network Error" and if I resume then it downloads the html of the webpage rather than the file.

Here is the code:

```
public static void SendFile(HttpResponse response, string fileName, string contentType, byte[] fileData)
{

    BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(response.OutputStream);


    response.Clear();
    response.ContentType = contentType;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", $"attachment; filename={fileName};");

    writer.Write(fileData);
    writer.Flush();

    response.Flush();
    response.Close();
    response.End();

}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] including how that function is called and the parameters involved.

Comment: I'm not sure I can easily give a complete verifiable example because it would involve a pdf file.  But the call I make to this function is like the following:

protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
     SaveFile.SendFile(Response, "FileName.pdf", "application/pdf", fileBytes);
}

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the fielname in double quotes. e.g. `...; filename=\"{fileName}\";");`

Comment: Just tried it with quotes, no difference.

Comment: So you can try a functioning example at http://www.inferant.com, just click the button to download.  You can download the actual file at http://www.inferant.com/c4611_sample_explain.pdf and you can download a complete project at http://www.inferant.com/PushFile.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function that works on all browsers with the advantage of working from a class outside the page:

```
public static void SendToBrowser(string virtualPath)
{
    string FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath);
    System.IO.FileInfo TargetFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(FilePath);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + TargetFile.Name);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", TargetFile.Length.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(TargetFile.FullName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I added Button2 to my sample with your code behind it and got the same results.  I have usually found that Chrome is the most forgiving but in this one case it's the other way round.  I'm also wondering if there is some sort of setup on the server that is required.

Comment: I take it back.  It does work but only because the file actually exists in the file system.  Mine does not.  The file is only in memory and I don't want to ever write it to the file system on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `response.Close();`, seems that Chrome doesn't like it.

By removing that line of code it works not only in Chrome, but Firefox, IE, and Edge.